# How to read all input field and saved it in one go of all tabs generated dynamically in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Creating tab by selecting no. from picklist.

```
<lightning-tabset>
       <template for:each={lstTabs} for:item="tab">
          <lightning-tab label={tab.Name} key={tab.Name}>
             {tab.Name} 
           <!-- here having n nu. of input field-->
 </lightning-tab>
       </template>
</lightning-tabset>
```

**JS:**

```
numberOftabs(event){
        //this.lstTabs = null;
        let no = parseInt(event.detail.value);
        for(let i=1;i<=no;i++){           
            this.lstTabs.push({Id:i, Name : 'Applicant ' + i});
            console.log(this.lstTabs);
        }
    }
```

Tabs is getting created.
How to read values of all the input on click of save button to send it to apex to create no of records.

Comment: welcome to SFSE,  `lightning-tabset` working as lazy loading , means loads the content  only for active tab(when ever tab click). you can not have all the tabs content at a time.

Comment: How to get the content of active tab. i can add in array on one by one by clicking on tab

Comment: by using `onactive` event , can you check out here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tabset/example

Comment: @sdandamud1 Close. Don't say "lazy loading", that means something else entirely. It's more accurate to say "only the current tab is rendered".

Comment: @sfdcfox Agreed

Comment: <lightning-input type="text"  variant="label-hidden" label="Enter some text"></lightning-input> ..This is input in all tabs...On Active tab, how to get input values on js.